# Logs do apache: verificando um ataque slowloris

Tags: apache, segurança

Estou fazendo simulação de um ataque *slowloris* a um servidor Debian rodando Apache.

As máquinas atacantes são Debian também.

A fim de me certificar de que o ataque *slowloris* foi efetivo, gostaria de acessar os *logs* do Apache e verificar se a negação de serviço ocorreu, isto é, se ele em algum momento, parou de aceitar conexões, o estado dos *buffers* e etc.
O horário dos ataques são conhecidos.

O Apache fornece tais informações? Onde verificar no Debian?
Alguma sugestão do que mais verificar?

É possível "limpar os logs" (depois de fazer backup) para recomeçar os experimentos? Como fazê-lo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existem dois logs relevantes que podes querer verificar:

- `error.log`, todos os erros que possam ter ocorrido no serviço, geralmente em `/var/log/apache2/error.log`
- `access.log`, logs dos acessos (horas, ip de origem, metodo HTTP, url a que acedeu, User-Agent), geralmente em `/var/log/apache2/access.log`

Para recomeçar os logs (apagar os conteudos), se quiseres faz backup antes:

```
cd /var/log/apache2
cp access.log access.backup1.log
cp error.log error.backup1.log
```

E para apagar o conteúdo:

```
cd /var/log/apache2
sudo cp /dev/null access.log
sudo cp /dev/null error.log
```

**Dica:**

O que costumo fazer principalmente com o `error.log` é segui-lo em tempo real em um terminal:

```
tailf -10 caminho/para/error.log
```

isto quer dizer:
`tailf`: *follow* (seguir) ultimo conteudo do ficheiro

`-10`: ultimas 10 linhas

Comment: Se eu apagar esses logs, ele cria de novo os arquivos ou pode dar problemas no Apache?

Comment: Não convém apagar, o que eu faço é apagar o conteudo só, editei essa parte @EdS

Comment: "server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting" é um bom indicativo da negacao de serviço?

Comment: Nunca vi esse erro mas pelo descrito faz sentido que isso seja um dos sintomas de ddos @EdS

Comment: Não conheço muito do Apache mas tem um comando "apachectl fullstatus |more"  Ele lista conexões, se está aceitando, etc.... Isso fica depois armazenado em algum lugar? Nos logs acima, eu não achei!

Comment: @EdS vê se isto ajuda: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/use-httpd-fullstatus-to-monitor-apache-status/

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55531/discussion-between-miguel-and-ed-s).